# php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force gives FatalThrowableError

Tags: php, powershell, doctrine-orm, symfony

Here is the result of the command in PowerShell

```
PS C:\wamp\www\xxx> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

←[37;41m                                                            ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '{'  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m                                                            ←[39;49m

←[32mdoctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] ←[39m←[32m<command>←[39m
```

What do I need to look into? I don't see a line number anywhere telling me where to address the error.

Also, on a side note, what is with the "←[37;41m" and "←[39;49m" everytime I run a Symfony command? It is making everything very hard to read.

Edit: Updated with an image

[Image of PowerShell Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJzkY.png)

Comment: ←[37;41m" and "←[39;49m are colors, for prompt supporting them.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you are using forward slash and windows is expecting back slash.

Can you try:

```
php bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

If that doesn't work, also try in a standard command prompt, not PowerShell.

Comment: I gave it a shot and ended up with the same error, edited post with an image

Comment: What version of PHP is installed with the wamp server? This works fine for me on windows both with forward and backward slashes, except I'm using xampp instead of wamp.